# null exception when adding form to dll

Tags: c#, winforms, interface

I have a simple dll. I use 'interface' to load my dll into my main application. The problem is I want dll to have form, so I add a new form into dll project. But whenever I load my dll into main app and try to call any methods, I get: null exception:

```
   ..
   Type[] pluginTypes = Assembly.LoadFile(s).GetTypes();

   foreach (Type t in pluginTypes){
     M.ModuleInterface module = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as M.ModuleInterface;
     module.ReadAll(); // exception
   }

   // Exception I'm getting
   t.GenericParameterAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

If I remove the form from the dll, the exception disappears and everything is working great. How can I add the form and fix this exception? Thanks!

Comment: does your form implement the ModuleInterface?

Comment: Have you considered MEF for this? Its more suited for composing pluggable applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can occur because not all types in your dll implements `ModuleInterface` interface.

Try this:

```
Type[] pluginTypes = Assembly.LoadFile(s).GetTypes();

foreach (Type t in pluginTypes)
{
    if(t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ModuleInterface)))
    {
        var module = (ModuleInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        module.ReadAll(); // exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because u do not initialize the form in the dll method. Try passing your form as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should filter for all the elements of the desired type before looping:

```
foreach(Type t in pluginTypes.Where(type=>typeof(M.ModuleInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type))){
   M.ModuleInterface module = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as M.ModuleInterface;
   module.ReadAll();
}
```